# Javascript/SOAP Error Calling Salesforce Apex Web Service Method

Tags: javascript, soap, salesforce, apex

Hoping someone can shed some light on a pesky error that some of my users are seeing in Salesforce. We have a custom button that invokes a VF page containing javascript calls into Apex web services. One particular call is failing with the error message:

> faultcode:'soapenv:Client', faultstring:'The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup'

Here is the javascript method making the call:

```
function copyQPP(quoteResult) 
{
    var qRecords = new sforce.QueryResultIterator(quoteResult);

    if(qRecords.hasNext())
    {
        $('#StatusMessage').html(' Copying Quotes and Products...');        
        var qRecord = qRecords.next();
        var state = {qRecords : qRecords};          
        var callback = {onSuccess: copyQPPs, onFailure: optyFailure, source: state};
        sforce.apex.execute('OpportunityCopyRenewalService2','copyQuoteFromOpty', {copyType:"COPY", NewOptyId:newOpp ,QuoteId:qRecord.Id}, callback);           
    }
    else
    {
        updateProducts('');
    }
}
```

And here is the Apex webservice method being called:

```
webservice static Id copyQuoteFromOpty(String CopyType,Id NewOptyId,Id QuoteId ) {

    Id newQuoteId;
    try {
        newQuoteId=copyRenewQuote(CopyType,NewOptyId,QuoteId, true);
        Id[] PPs=new List<Id>();  
        for (Proposed_Product__c aPP :  [Select Id from Proposed_Product__c where Quote__c=:QuoteId Limit 1000] ) {
            PPs.add(aPP.Id);
        }

        List<Id> PPreturn = copyRenewPPs(CopyType,newQuoteId,NewOptyId,PPs);         
    }

    catch (Exception e){
        system.debug(e);
    }

    System.Debug('****************************************************Exiting copyQuoteFromOpty. Returning Quote ID: ' + newQuoteId);
    return newQuoteId;     
}
```

As you can see from the callback definition, I'm expecting control to move on to the copyQPPs function. Instead, when the service method completes - and it does so successfully, no exception is thrown by the DML - control goes to the optyFailure function.

This is only happening to a subset of users. The QA analyst I'm working with is using the same exact version of IE that I am using: v9.0.8112.16421, but she is getting the error and I am not. Also, the error occurs for her regardless of whether she's in Compatibility View or not. (I know, that's only supposed to affect rendering, but I've seen stranger things.)

Comment: What if the tester uses a different browser? Just trying to narrow down the cause...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that an exception is occurring within the `copyQuoteFromOpty` web service and is being handled by the try catch block. As such the `newQuoteId` is null on return.

Comment out the try and catch to see what the actual error is.

Comment: I checked the debug logs. Control never enters the Catch block.